# PDO Transaction doesn catch exceptions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying PDO  transactions for the first time. The below code doesnt work. the email address we are trying to insert has a duplicate so it should fail. It does give me an error. but the first insert get inserted into the DB and it doesnt roll back. I know rollback work cuase if i move PDO::rollBack into the Try{ before commit, it does roll back. I think the problem is its not catching the error, therefore not calling PDO::rollBack. Any ideas?

```
try {
    PDO::beginTransaction();

$sql = "INSERT INTO .`tblUsersIDvsAgencyID` (`id`, `agency_id`) VALUES (NULL, :agencyID)";
$STH = $this->prepare($sql); 
$STH->bindParam(':agencyID', $AgencyUser['agency_id']);
$STH->execute();
$userID = parent::lastInsertId();

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUsersEmailAddress` (`id`, `user_id`, `email_address`, `primary`, `created_ts`, `email_verified`) VALUES (NULL ,  :userID ,  :EmailAddress ,  '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,  '0' )";
$STH = $this->prepare($sql); 
$STH->bindParam(':userID', $userID);
$STH->bindParam(':EmailAddress', $email_address);
$STH->execute();
PDO::commit();
echo 'Data entered successfully<br />';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
/*** roll back the transaction if we fail ***/
PDO::rollBack();
echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the transaction methods statically like: `PDO::beginTransaction();`? You should be calling them non-statically like: `$this->beginTransaction();`. At least, I would think it needs a specific connection to know where to apply the transaction calls on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PDO::beginTransaction()` is not a static method. From your question, it looks like you're extending the PDO class. I wouldn't do that as I doubt you're adding anything significant to the base class. Instead, you should the set the PDO connection as a class property.

For example

```
class ParentClass
{
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct(PDO $dbh)
    {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;

        // Make sure PDO is set to throw exceptions
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function insertStuff()
    {
        $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
        try {
            // do stuff

            $this->dbh->commit();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->dbh->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Phil ya iam extending this class to another parents class which extends to PDO. The reason why i did it like this is that when i call a function from this class to its parents class, and the parents class does some DB related function it will use the same connection.

Comment: @fireeyedboy how else should i do it? should i have this classes constructor build the DBH connection?

Comment: @MofCA I think you're not understanding the concept of inheritance. When you call a `parent::` method, you aren't calling an operation on another object. It is the same instance. My comment still stands however, you're better off *not* extending PDO

Comment: @M.: Preferably, you should pass the PDO object to the constructor of the consuming object, something like the following: http://pastie.org/2378109 That way, you can easily create another instance of the consuming object with another PDO connection. This is called loose coupling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). It keeps your code flexible, and not tied together by hardcoding it (in the constructor for instance).

Comment: @MofCA I've updated my answer with a fuller OOP implementation

Comment: @fireeyedboy I think we shared brain-space there for a minute

Comment: @Phil and fireeyedboy worked pefectly... thank you guys... it took me a second to change around all my code, but it looks like it working fine. So this is dev mode, when in product mode, how do we turn off all these PDO errors. but keep rollBack still working.

Comment: @MofCA That's really a topic for another question. In short, you change the way your application handles and displays error messages

Comment: @Phil any thing you recommend i read to learn more about this?

Comment: @MofCA You should ask another question. Outline what you're currently doing and ask how people would handle errors in different environments (dev, test, prod, etc). You're sure to get some great responses

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to start by quoting the docs:

> Beware: Some MySQL table types (storage engines) do not support transactions. When writing transactional database code using a table type that does not support transactions, MySQL will pretend that a transaction was initiated successfully. In addition, any DDL queries issued will implicitly commit any pending transactions.

Your problem may be expected behavior. Additionally:

1. `beginTransaction` is not static. (I repeat Phil's statement that you should not be extending PDO).
2. Call $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
3. You never call `closeCursor` on your statement (this will often cause problems). (Phil points out that it is not explicitly necessary in this case. It is still best practice though).
4. Using `bindParam` does not yield any benefit for the userID variable as you are using it (a locally defined variable which is not re-used).

Comment: 3. You don't need to call `closeCursor()` on an insert statement. The statement is closed as soon as it's executed. 4. Preparing statements compiles and often caches the statement on the DB server. Were this query to be run again with different parameters, the benefits are obvious. Basically, all variable (non constant) query "values" should be parametrised

Comment: @Phil 3 -- knee jerk reaction. I've seen open cursors wreck havoc. This means that now, any time I see a second query without a `closeCursor` I point it out. 4. That was a case of unfortunate inaccuracy on my part -- I could have said that better and I've rephrased it a little.

Comment: Oh, I hear you about closing cursors. I always close my `SELECT` statements, even if they've run their course.